# Pass data from a routed component into a child of the app component

Tags: javascript, angular

I will post some code below, however, what I am trying achieve is that on a select few pages, the background of the header will become transparent unless scrolled (however, the default should be white).

**app.component.html**

```
<section>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})

export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input() scrolled: boolean = false;

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
      this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;
  }
}
```

This seems to work, however, on say the profile page, I want to disable this functionality, how would go about settings something on the profile.component.ts (routed) to say to the header component (in app.component.ts) 'hey, don't enable the scroll functionality'?

Comment: You can query the params.

 ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params['name'];
  });
}

Comment: Since you are trying to pass data from any component to a child of app component, you could try to implement a solution doing the communication through a service `providedIn: 'root'`. Maybe using a `Subject` from rxjs to be able to react when a child submit a value.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to disable some functionality on the header component for a certain route you could use the `Router` and listen to the route changes and do something only if it matches the route pattern or vice versa.

```
// app-header.component.ts
export class AppHeader implements OnInit {
  doSomethingRoutes = ['/page-a', '/page-c'];
  dontDoScrollFunctionality = false;
  constructor (private router: Router) {};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
           if (doSomethingRoutes.includes(event.url)){
               //...write your logic here?
               // something like this ....
               dontDoScrollFunctionality = false;
           } else {
              dontDoScrollFunctionality = true;
           }
        }
    })
  }
  
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
      this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;
      if (!this.dontDoScrollFunctionality) {
          // ... do scroll logic
      } else {
         // whatever you want here
      }
  }

}
```

Im not sure if i've answered the question but i implemented a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z2qyuu?file=src/header/header.component.ts) here, where if youre on `/page-a` scrolling will turn the `Hello` red and if youre on `/page-b` it will turn the `Hello` yellow. A caveat here is that your will prolly need to filter out the query params and other stuff from the `event.url` before trying to match if its the route to do the functionality.